# Почему пропадает объект и он плохо рисуется jCanvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Всем привет, хочу задать вопрос, почему пропадает мой объект, когда я выхожу за рамки `canvas`, и почему прямоугольник не правильно рисуется при перемещении мыши.
Прикладываю код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $canvas = $('canvas');
    var rect = {};
    var drawing = false;
    var trigger = $('.rect');

    function _makeRect() {
        var startX = $('.coordinate_x').val();
        var startY = $('.coordinate_y').val();
        var width = $('.rect_width').val();
        var height = $('.rect_width').val();

        $canvas.drawRect({
           fillStyle: '#000',
           draggable: true,
           fromCenter: false,
           x: startX, y: startY,
           width: width, height: height
        });

        console.log(startX, startY, width, height);
    }

    $('.make_rect').on('click', _makeRect);

    $canvas.on('mousedown', _mousedown);
    $canvas.on('mouseup', _mouseup);
    $canvas.on('mousemove', _drawing);

    function _mousedown(e) {
        drawing = true;
        var startX = e.pageX - $canvas.offset().left;
        var startY = e.pageY - $canvas.offset().top;
        rect.x = startX;
        rect.y = startY;
    }

    function _mouseup(e) {
        drawing = false;
    }

    function _drawing(e) {
        var currentX = e.pageX - $canvas.offset().left;
        var currentY = e.pageY - $canvas.offset().top;
        if(drawing) {
            $canvas.drawRect({
               fillStyle: '#000',
               layer: true,
               name: 'box',
               fromCenter: false,
               x: rect.x, y: rect.y,
               width: currentX - rect.x, height: currentY - rect.y
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `var height = $('.rect_width').val();` Начнем с того, что тут ошибка. Обращается не к тому полю. К тому же было бы полезно, чтобы ты прикладывал к примеру ссылку на jsfiddle.net - будет проще и быстрее тебе помочь (ну или хотябы приложи еще и свой html).

Comment: в html все просто там только тег canvas, 
и кнопки

Comment: и почему это не к тому полю?)

Comment: аа =) Я тебя понял - просто я смотрел дальше, чтобы рисовать не только квадраты, а вообще "квадратные фигуры". Прощу прощения =)

Comment: http://thunders.rpr.by/ Вот здесь можно проблему увидеть

Comment: Поясни пожалуйста, что значит "почему пропадает мой объект, когда я выхожу за рамки canvas". ? Просто библиотека jcanvas позволяет отлавливать все объекты на канвасе и ты можешь программно "заставить" объекты вернуться на позицию (0,0).

Comment: Я имею ввиду когда я отрисовал прямоугольник, а потом мышкой вышел за границы canvas мои нарисованные объекты пропадают, как их сохранять?

Answer (score 1):

Могу подсказать только часть ответа.

> почему прямоугольник не правильно рисуется при перемещении мыши.

Потому что ты постоянно прорисовывашь твой прямоугольник. Решение достаточно простое - тебе нужно просто поменять логику на следующее:

1. Нажимаем на кнопку -> drawing = true -> событие mouseDown;
2. при перемещении в блоке if (drawing) нужно сохранять текущие значения Х и Y (например lastX и lastY) -> событие mouseMove ;
3. Отпускаем кнопку мыши - drawing = false и срабаотывает событие mouseUp. В нем мы должны добавить логику отрисовки, используя
   сохраненные значения lastX и LastY (ну и startX и startY) и потом очистить их для
   дальнейшего использования;

Что получаем в итоге: При mousedown - заполненые значения StartX и StartY, MouseMove - заполненые значения LastX и LastY. На mouseUp - все 4 переменные для рисования фигуры. Однако это решение не идеально - возможно ты хочешь видеть сам прямоугольник во время рисования.

Comment: Я должен видеть прямоугольник при рисовании тоже

Comment: Есть предложение использовать слои так, чтобы во время рисования создавался "временный" слой поверх текущего с opacity равный 0.1 и на нем рисовался бы объект с постоянной очисткой канваса (не очень решение, но первое что на ум пришло). После того, как мы решили оставить фигуру - мы передаем координаты на основной слой, рисуем объект и удаляем слой рисования. Для упрощения данных процессов можно попробовать использовать fabric.js - там это можно сделать гораздо проще